# Type 'apr_pool_t' could not be resolved Eclipse C/C++

Tags: c, apache, ubuntu

I am creating an apache module using eclipse c/c++ on eclipse but I am getting this error `Type 'apr_pool_t' could not be resolved Eclipse C/C++`
I included `/usr/include/apache` and `/usr/lib`
where is the structure **apr_pool_t**?

Comment: please provide a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself. It is as simple as include /usr/include/apr-1.0 in right click on my project properties->C/C++General->Paths & Symbols.